# "Error: no device found" when using Ledger Nano S Plus with Solana CLI

Tags: cli, ledger-nano

The Solana CLI tools are unable to detect a Ledger Nano S Plus hardware wallet.  What do I need to do to make it work?

```
$ solana -k usb://ledger?key=0/0 address
Error: no device found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the USB Product IDs for the Ledger Nano S Plus had not been added to the `solana-remote-wallet` crate until `v1.10.31` and `v1.11.3`.  Updating the CLI tools to one of these versions, or newer resolves the issue.

Additionally, Linux users may need to [update their ledger hardware udev rules](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/udev-rules) to pick up similar additions

Comment: I have v1.2.0 of the solana app on my ledger and v1.14.12 of the solana cli app on my ubuntu 20.04 and I updated my udev rules per your github project but I still get "Error: no device found", what would be the next troubleshooting steps?

my dmesg looks good as well:
[ 2032.166872] hid-generic 0003:2C97:1015.000B: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Ledger Nano S] on usb-0000:00:06.0-2/input0
[ 2032.206529] hid-generic 0003:2C97:1015.000C: hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Ledger Nano S] on usb-0000:00:06.0-2/input1

Comment: as per your dmesg output, your device is a ledger nano s.  this post is about the ledger nano s plus.  please create a new post for your issue